# Inactive monitors turn black > Need to reconnect cable

Tags: windows-8.1, multiple-monitors

Here's what happens:

When I'm not using my computer for a bit  my screens go black (screensaver or whatever) but when I return and try to use my computer, the screens stay black. Not the turned off kind of black, but the black 'light' from which you can tell the monitors are on. They do not display a 'no signal' sign. And the computer is still fully working because for example if I have a video left open, and press the spacebar, the sound still works. Turning the monitors on and off doesn't work. Only reconnecting as much as 1 cable of the 2 monitors works.

My graphics card is an AMD Radeon R9 380 Nitro if that matters. And the monitors are connected by DVI.

Comment: If power cycling the displays doesn't help then the outputs themselves are sleeping. Its a software fault most likely. If you arent on the latest catalyst drivers, install them. If you *are* on the latest, roll back 2-3 versions and test.

Comment: I'll try to roll back the drivers. It's weird though, because this didn't happen for more than a month (I just got this pc) and I haven't even updated the software

Comment: Okay this is weird I downloaded and installed the 14.12 driver, but it still says I'm on 15.7.1? lol

Comment: Uninstall the current driver, check the "delete files" box, then install 14.12.